# ビジュアルプログラミングのOS環境について

Tags: ios, aibo-visual-programming

持っていたiPadのOSが低かった為最新のiPadに買い替え今日届きました。
iPadのOSは13.5.1です。それでも「お使いのブラウザに対応していません」と言われてしまいます。
このビジュアルプログラムをしたいだけで買い替えたのに、どうしたらよいか途方に暮れています。
デスクトップのPCではビジュアルプログラムはすでにやっており、aiboと一緒に持ち歩きたくて今回買い換えた次第です。
何の設定が悪いかアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？
買ったiPadはミニで最新バージョンです。

Comment: サポートサイトのFAQを読む限り「iPadOS 13 以降の場合：Safari ver.13 以降」となっているようなので、念のため使用しているブラウザの種類とバージョンも確認してみてください。 / 場合によっては iOS の最新版にビジュアルプログラミングの環境が対応できていない可能性もあり、こちらの場合は [オーナーサポート](http://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html) に直接要望を出す形になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo ビジュアルプログラミングの動作環境につきましては、
aibo ビジュアルプログラミングの下記 FAQ をご確認ください。
https://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/#faq4

> 「iPadOS 13 以降の場合：Safari ver.13 以降」

上記でも解決されない場合は、aiboオーナーサポートへお問い合わせください。
https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact

> 「aiboの飼い方、ご購入前の相談など、aiboに関するすべてのお問い合わせは以下のaibo専用窓口へお問い合わせください。」

- メールでのお問い合わせ
  　https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry_mail/?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_mail
  　上記リンク先において、注意事項に同意いただいた上、
  　「同意してメールで問い合わせる」ボタンを押してください。
- チャットでのお問い合わせ
  　https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry/chat.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_chat
  　上記リンク先にある「上記内容を確認して自動応答サービスを開始する」を押してください。
- LINE でのお問い合わせ
  　https://www.sony.jp/support/inquiry_line.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_line
  　LINE公式アカウントから、お問い合わせをいただけます。
  　リンク先にある「友だち追加」ボタンをクリックするか、「QRコード」を読み取ってください。

また、Stackoverflow はソニーの外部サイトであり、
質問はプログラミングのことに限定していただきますようお願いいたします。
詳しくはこちらをご参照ください。
https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact#devevisu
・質問の例
　「〇〇のプログラムを実行したいのですが、どうすればできますか？」
　「APIでエラーが発生します。原因は何でしょうか？」

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム